# jQuery UI version update to 1.12.1 causing initialization error

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have updated jQuery UI in my project from version 1.8.24 to 1.12.1. In version 1.8.24 the code below was running successfully without any errors but after the update the line mentioned below throws an error.

```
interface JQuery {
   picker(options?: any): any;
}

export function showCarAllocationDetails(elem) {
   var picker = $("#car_allocation_details .ima-picker input:hidden");
   (<any>picker).picker('clear');   --> this line throws an error
}
```

The error is **Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on picker prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'clear'**

I couldn't figure out what exactly is causing the error as it was working fine in the previous version. Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Where is `picker()` defined?

Comment: The picker method defined in the interface is mentioned above

Comment: It seems that you're calling an option of the `picker()` before you've initialized the `picker()`. So maybe `(<any>picker).picker().picker('clear');`